# I am using LINQ to connect to a database and i get a list of properties and I want to convert it to an XML File

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Below is what I use to log into the database using linq and then I use C# expressions to gather the data I want.  The next thing I want to do is convert this data into an XML any Ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Data;

namespace VcacManagementTools.BuildProfiles
{
    public static class BuildProfileTools
    {
        public static ICollection<string> GetExistingBuildProfileNames(string repositoryHostname,
                                                                       string repositoryUsername,
                                                                       string repositoryPassword)
        {

            var url = string.Format("https://{0}/repository/data/ManagementModelEntiti.svc", repositoryHostname);

            var managementModelClient = new DynamicOps.ManagementModel.ManagementModelEntities(new Uri(url))
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(repositoryUsername, repositoryPassword)
                };



            return managementModelClient
                .GlobalProfiles
                .Select(gp => gp.ProfileName)
                .ToList();
```

The Output I recieve is a list of values

Comment: If you are familiar with LINQ, why not try LINQ to XML, lots of great tools there with similar syntax to other LINQ feature.

Comment: Are you using DataTable that you're declaring in your code?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter sorry that was a mistake

Comment: @Evanlewis sorry I am new to C# and not really familar with LINQ yet do you know a website with tutorials?

Comment: Pretty good tutorial here, for your needs refer to Section 2 (or question 9).  [LINQ to XML Tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you want to take the data (the list contains the data from the database) and put it in XML file. I used variables to show where to put each data.

In case you have an XML:

```
try
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(spath, LoadOptions.SetBaseUri);
    foreach(String propertyData in dataList)
    {
        XElement root = new XElement(ElementName);
        root.Add(new XElement("property1", propertyData));
        doc.Element(MainElement).Add(root);
    }
    doc.Save(spath);
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```